# How to make NMAP command steady and the fastest possible?

Tags: security

I want to make an IP scan using NMAP, but the operating time varies for some reason. The command can be executed in 2 seconds, and if I launch it again just after, it can take 30 seconds.

This is the command I use :

```
nmap -n -sn -T5 --max-rtt-timeout 1s
```

`-n` : no DNS resolution

`-sn` : disable port scan

`-T5` fast mode

`--max-rtt-timeout` round trip timeout for the probes 1s

I don't know if my optimisation is good. How do I make it better ?

Comment: That would depend on what it is you are scanning

Comment: run `nmap -v` or under `strace` to see if what `nmap` is wedging on is apparent?